# Passing a date from form into MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to create a form that adds an event to my calendar by adding it to my MySQL database.

This is the form:

```
<form action="actions.php?action=addEvent" method="post">
    Titel: <input type="text" name="title"><br/>
    Start tid(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM): <input type="text" name="startDate"><br/>
    Slut tid(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM): <input type="text" name="endDate"><br/>
    Beskrivning: <br/>
    <textarea rows="15" cols="10" name="description"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Spara">
</form>
```

this is the PHP script:

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'addEvent'){
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
    $startDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['startDate'] . ":00"));
    $endDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['endDate'] . ":00"));

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO events VALUES (null, '$title', '$desc', $startDate, $endDate);") or header("Location: ./?p=calendar.php&msg=" . mysql_error());
    header("Location: ./?p=calendar.php&msg=Sparat");
}
```

The MySQL column type is DATETIME. How should i proceed to convert the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM strings from the form to a type that lets the mysql_query() work. Currently i get the ?msg=Sparat response but no row is entered into the database.

Comment: I'd name the columns in the insert. insert into events (col1, col2...) values ('','',...)

Comment: I'd use a stored procedure too. Or put quotes around the dates.

Comment: Have you at least tried to echo your variables if the are not empty?
Also add this to your query http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php. to determine what errors are present in your current query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to surround the `dates` fields with quotes,

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO events VALUES (null, '$title', '$desc', '$startDate', '$endDate');") or header("Location: ./?p=calendar.php&msg=" . mysql_error());
```

Comment: I feel very stupid, but that did the trick! I guess it was worth coming here for the first time.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the query to have single quotes around the date.  Please read [this](http://www.ntchosting.com/mysql/insert-date.html).

```
$query_manual = "INSERT INTO tablename (col_name, col_date) VALUES ('DATE: Manual Date', '2008-7-04')";
```

Also, asking your user to type the date in that format might be a little cumbersome.  People expect datepickers theses days. [Here's](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) a very simple one I use frequently from jqueryui.  You can format the input date as YYYY-MM-DD.  If you need to add the time, you can extend the jquery datepicker to be a [timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

Answer (score 0):

the date you are receiving is in the correct format. So you need not to change it. You just need to put single quotes around date while using in mysql_query. So you can:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO events VALUES (null, '$title', '$desc', '".$_POST['startDate']."', '".$_POST['endDate']."');") or header("Location: ./?p=calendar.php&msg=" . mysql_error());
```